# Special school code dealing with functions and return value issues

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value

Here is a special problem we have been working on for my 100 level class and we recently added functions to the code. I can seem to figure exactly what to do to get this code to run. Also, my teacher says that the return value is not need for my variable getSID which is kind of confusing to me, any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//here are the function prototypes for my problem
int getSID(int &);
int getResidentStatus(int &);
double calculateTuition(double, double, double, double, double, double);
double calculateTax(double &);

int main()
{//declared variables
    char name[20], address[30], veteran, runningStart;
    int credits, SID, residency;
    double tuitionCost, taxDeductible, serviceFee, techFee, facilitiesFee, studentCenterFee, tuitionCostAndFees;

    cout << "***********************************" << endl;
    cout << "*                                 *" << endl;
    cout << "*  Green River Community College  *" << endl;
    cout << "*                                 *" << endl;
    cout << "*        12401 SE 320th St.       *" << endl;
    cout << "*      Auburn, WA, 98092-3622     *" << endl;
    cout << "*                                 *" << endl;
    cout << "*      Phone (253) 833-9111       *" << endl;
    cout << "*                                 *" << endl;
    cout << "***********************************" << endl;

    cout << "Enter name:";
    cin.getline(name, 20);
    getSID(SID);//my teacher says this doesn't need to use a return value?
    getResidentStatus(residency);
    cout << "Are you a veteran(y or n)?:";
    cin >> veteran;
    while (!(veteran == 'y' || veteran == 'n'))
    {
        cout << "Enter either 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: ";
        cin >> veteran;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Are you involved in the running start program(y or n)?:";
    cin >> runningStart;
    while (!(runningStart == 'y' || runningStart == 'n'))
    {
        cout << "Enter either 'y' for yes or 'n' for no: ";
        cin >> runningStart;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Enter home address(street address, and city):";
    cin.getline(address, 30);
    cout << "Enter number of credits:";
    cin >> credits;
    serviceFee = credits*0.5;
    if (credits <= 12)
    {
        techFee = credits * 5;
    }
    else if (credits>12)
    {
        techFee = 60;
    }
    if (residency == 1 && credits>18)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 18)*268.26) + (149 * 8) + (278.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 1 && credits>10)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 10) * 149) + (278.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 1 && credits <= 10)
    {
        tuitionCost = (credits*278.84);
    }
    if (residency == 2 && credits>18)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 18)*109.26) + (53.68 * 8) + (119.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 2 && credits>10)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 10)*53.68) + (119.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 2 && credits <= 10)
    {
        tuitionCost = (credits*119.84);
    }
    if (residency == 3 && credits>18)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 18)*96.26) + (52.99 * 8) + (106.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 3 && credits>10)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 10)*52.99) + (106.84 * 10);
    }
    else if (residency == 3 && credits <= 10)
    {
        tuitionCost = (credits*106.84);
    }
    if (veteran == 'y'&&credits>18)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 18)*96.26) + (52.99 * 8) + (96.26 * 10);
    }
    else if (veteran == 'y'&&credits>10)
    {
        tuitionCost = ((credits - 10)*52.99) + (96.26 * 10);
    }
    else if (veteran == 'y'&&credits <= 10)
    {
        tuitionCost = (credits*96.26);
    }
    if (runningStart == 'y')
    {
        tuitionCostAndFees = 0;
    }
    if (credits <= 10)
    {
        facilitiesFee = 17.5 + (credits - 5)*3.5;
    }
    else
        facilitiesFee = 35;
    studentCenterFee = 25;
    calculateTuition(tuitionCostAndFees, tuitionCost, serviceFee, facilitiesFee, studentCenterFee, techFee);//This line seems to be the main problem as to why it won't run!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    calculateTax(tuitionCostAndFees);
    cout << "Your name is: " << name << endl;
    cout << "Your student identification number is: " << SID << endl;
    cout << "Your address is : " << address << endl;
    cout << "You are taking " << credits << " credits this quarter. " << endl;
    cout << "The total cost of your tuition is: $" << tuitionCostAndFees << endl;
    cout << "The total tax deductible amount is: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << taxDeductible << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}//function definitions
int getSID(int & SID)
{
    cout << "Enter your student identification number: " << endl;
    cin >> SID;
    return SID;
}
int getResidentStatus(int & residency)
{
    cout << "Are you an international student(1), non-washington resident(2) or washington resident(3)?: " << endl;
    cin >> residency;
    while (!(residency == 1 || residency == 2 || residency == 3))
    {
        cout << "Enter either 1, 2 or 3";
        cin >> residency;
    }
    return residency;
}
double calculateTuition(double & tuitionCostAndFees, double & tuitionCost, double & serviceFee, double facilitiesFee, double & studentCenterFee, double & techFee)
{
    tuitionCostAndFees = tuitionCost + serviceFee + facilitiesFee + studentCenterFee + techFee;
    return tuitionCostAndFees;
}
double calculateTax(double & tuitionCostAndFees, double & taxDeductible)
{
    taxDeductible = tuitionCostAndFees*.125;
    return taxDeductible;
}
```

Comment: Did your professor happen to mention anything about *magic numbers*?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher means that you should code like this `void getSID(int &);` and do the same thing for its definition。

Answer (score 1):

You have declared the functions CalculateTuition with parameters as double:

```
calculateTuition(double, double, double, double, double, double);
```

This will be called in case of call by value.

However in function definition which you have done after main you have tried to invoke the parameters by reference. This will give an error. As while calling the function as below:

```
calculateTuition(tuitionCostAndFees, tuitionCost, serviceFee, facilitiesFee, studentCenterFee, techFee);
```

you are sending double values (i.e, declared as: double tuitionCost, taxDeductible, serviceFee, techFee, facilitiesFee, studentCenterFee, tuitionCostAndFees;)

This will try to access the function definition above. It does not read the function defined after main.

Try this instead:

```
calculateTuition(double &, double &, double &, double &, double &, double &);
```

in your function declaration. This should work.